# Setting Boundaries for user cancellation of trip

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa

I am building a booking system and trying to limit the user's cancellation of the trip if he/she tried to cancel it one week before the actual date of the trip.

In other words: The user booked the trip on July 1 and the trip starts on August 1. The user tried to cancel his/her booking of the trip on July 23rd. The system should block his/her request to cancel the trip. 
I wanna make this date validation work when the user try to cancel the trip before the start date. Can anyone help me to validate the date the user request to cancel the trip.
I have tried the code below but not sure if it is working properly

```
   This is the code I tried to implement:

     //Getting input values from jsp from                       
        LocalDate.parse(request.getParameter("startDate"));
        LocalDate endDate = (LocalDate) 
        LocalDate.parse(request.getParameter("endDate"));

        LocalDate startDate = (LocalDate) LocalDate.of(2020, 05, 01);
        LocalDate isexpDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 04, 01);
        if (startDate.minusWeeks(1).isBefore(isexpDate))
```

The start and end date should based on the user input

Comment: you have told us what you are building, you have told us what you want it to do, and you have told us what you have tried. You still have not told us what is the problem, what it is that you are having difficulty with.

Comment: @MikeNakis Ok I will update my question. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do it, using identifiers that are a bit more understandable than those provided, and dates that are in accordance with the dates mentioned in the question:

```
LocalDate tripDate = LocalDate.of(2020, 8, 1 );
LocalDate latestCancellationDate = tripDate.minusWeeks( 1 );
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.of( 2020, 7, 23 );
if( currentDate.isAfter( latestCancellationDate ) )
{
    /* prevent cancellation */
}
```

Beware that I have not actually tried to compile the above, it might need some slight modifications before it compiles without errors, but the logic should be correct.

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense and gives an idea of the logic